# Getting the info I get from the database using bookshelf in node/express?

Tags: node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I do search in all my users like this

```
      User.where({id: req.params.id}).fetchAll({columns:['id','email']}).then((resData) => {
            res.json(resData);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.json(err);
        });
```

and  get something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "name@gmail.com",
    }
]
```

But how can I access this data in my progrma. For example, before `res.json(resData)` do something like

```
if (resData.email == 'john@gmail.com') {
    res.json(resData);
} else {
    res.send(403);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you only want a single record, you have to use `fetch()`, not `fetchAll()`. Then you can use `.get()` to get individual attributes:

```
User.forge({id: req.params.id}).fetch({
  columns:['id','email']
}).then((resData) => {
  if (resData.get('email') === 'john@gmail.com') {
    res.json(resData);
  } else {
    res.send(403);
  }
})
```

Or, if you would like to look at all of the model's attributes they're available in:

```
 resData.attributes
```

Comment: this is not working. console.log(resData.attributes) gives me undefined and resData.get('email') === 'john@gmail.com' isn´t true when is suppose to

Comment: Wait, you're using `fetchAll()`. That returns a collection, but you only want one record. I've updated my answer with the correct code to use in this situation.